# Upload Firestore Cache Write Data Upon Getting Internet

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, offline-caching

My app allows the user make firestore writes when the user is offline. I have noticed that cache data is only written to firestone when the user makes another write (so it takes all the initial writes when user was offline, and then adds the new write data and send to firestore).

I am looking for a way to send the cached data to firestore without the user having to make another write entry. Please how can I achieve this functionality? I'd greatly appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: What do you mean by "when the user makes another write"?

Comment: So when a user adds more data, my app stores that data on the cloud. Assuming they did that at a point they don't have internet, those transactions are in cache. Entering more data when one has internet will result in the past entries now getting saved to the cloud in addition to the newly entered data. Now I want a way to just add the old data (when there was no internet) without having to enter new data (when there is data)

Comment: Why do you say "the past entries now getting saved to the cloud"? All the data that is stored in the cache will be added to the Cloud once the device regains connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this by detecting when the user gets an internet connection again, I suggest prompting the user before doing so. But when this event is done. I suggest writing to a dedicated location with a "last updated' field such as a dedicated collection for all users where you can track the last update timestamp, it'll incur a write but this way you have control over it.

It will require permission to check from the device such as a simple query to a `URL`, or ideally with the `getActiveNetworkInfo()` method from the ConnectivityManager returns a NetworkInfo instance representing the first connected network interface it can find or null if none of the interfaces are connected.

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

You will also need:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`
in your android manifest.

Note that having an active network interface doesn't guarantee that a particular networked service is available.